# How to set CUDA parameters with GTX1080 for Tensorflow?

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

After I install the diriver of GTX1080, tensorflow shows that it can find the cudnn library.

However, the GPU driver is not recognized by the modprobe. 
Detais information are as follows:

```
$ python
[14:22:14]
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352_uvm': Invalid argument
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: work-data
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: work-data
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:347] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  367.27  Thu Jun  9 18:53:27 PDT 2016 GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) """
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 367.27.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine.
```

The version of GTX1080 driver is 367.27, which is provided by the NVIDIA.

I don't know why there is a 'nvidia_352_uvm'?

The result of  `nvidia-smi` is here. 
May be I need to reinstall `cuda`, but I really reinstall it several times.
Should I remove all the cuda library and nvidia dirver, then reinstall them all? Is there any install sequence about this two?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3FQD.png)

Comment: This is very obviously be a broken CUDA installation

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but here are some tips I've learned after trying to get NVidia drivers to play nice with Ubuntu.

Upgrading new driver on top of existing driver gives a partially upgraded installation. You need to remove the previous stuff first.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf   # if you ran nvidia-xconfig
```

Reload NVidia driver as follows (from virtual terminal, CTRL+ALT+F7)

```
sudo service lightdm stop  # stop your window manager
killall python  # kill all running TensorFlow instances to free GPU
sudo modprobe -r nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia
dmesg | tail -100 # check for error messages
```

Check logs for any error messages from NVidia

```
dmesg | grep -i nvidia
lspci | grep -i nvidia
nvidia-smi     # make sure this reports version 367.27
```

Also, there are two ways to install drivers, using Ubuntu's built-in upgrade with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, or by getting tar ball from NVidia website. I was not able to get `sudo apt-get` route to work for TensorFlow, so I would recommend downloading drivers from NVidia website

Comment: I think the driver is ok, because the `nvidia-smi` show things right.

Comment: Nvidia_352_uvm must be left over from you previous installation